# Coded UI Unit Test Excel Connection String Not Working

Tags: c#, excel, unit-testing, connection-string, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to use coded ui with dynamic data from an excel spreadsheet (xlsx).  There seems to be an issue with my DataSource attribute. I get an error saying failed to connect to datasource.  Here is my connection string:

```
[DataSource("System.Data.Odbc", "Dsn=Excel Files;dbq=|DataDirectory|C:\\Test1.xlsx;defaultdir=C:\\;driverid=1046;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5", "Sheet1$", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), DeploymentItem("Test1.xlsx"), TestMethod]
```

The xlsx file is valid and at the correct location.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **dbq** clause looks wrong. The `|DataDirectory|` part is a parameter that is concatenated with the rest of the value. So in effect the clause is saying get the data from a file named `ValueOfDataDirectoryC:\\Test1.xlsx`. The Microsoft documentation (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624082.aspx) shows the example (line breaks added by me):

```
DataSource("System.Data.Odbc",
    "Dsn=Excel Files;Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};
        dbq=|DataDirectory|\\Data.xls;
        defaultdir=.;driverid=790;maxbuffersize=2048;
        pagetimeout=5;readonly=true",
    "Sheet1$", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), TestMethod]
```

Note the absence of any `C:` above.

Try changing the **dbq** clause to be `dbq=C:\\Test1.xlsx`.

Test

Comment: The text quoted from Microsoft has `Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};` and `;readonly=true` that are not in your text. Also, Microsoft say `driverid=790` you used `1046`. It may also be worth trying `.xlsx` in the `Driver=` clause.

Answer (score 2):

Save the file as xls instead of xlsx and remove "|DataDirectory|" from the connection string. This should help :)

Answer (score 1):

Add your `.Xls` file  to solution and make note of Path of the file

Try change

```
[DataSource("System.Data.Odbc", 
    "Dsn=Excel Files;Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};
        dbq=[FullPath Of your .xls file];
        defaultdir=.; driverid=790;
        maxbuffersize=2048; pagetimeout=5; readonly=true",
        "Sheet1$", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), TestMethod]
```

EG:

```
[DataSource("System.Data.Odbc", 
     "Dsn=Excel Files;Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};
        dbq=C:\\Users\\user1\\documents\\visual studio 2012\\Projects\\Demo\\Demo\\Book1.xlsx;
        defaultdir=.;driverid=790;
        maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5;readonly=true", 
        "Sheet1$", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), TestMethod]
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use xls file with this connection string:

```
[DataSource("System.Data.Odbc", @"Dsn=Excel Files;Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};dbq=C:\\Test1.xls;defaultdir=.;driverid=79‌​0;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5;readonly=true","Sheet1$", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), TestMethod]
```

had the same problem and thanks to here it's fixed now :)